# SQL to generate sequence for a set of columns depending on a select criteria

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an accounts journal entry table data like this:

```
TxnID   VchNo    SeqNo      Date    AccountName                TxnAmt   CrDr
103931  0        0     1-Apr-2011   ADVERTISEMENT                3600   D
103932  0        0     1-Apr-2011   MAYA OUTDOOR ADVERTISING     3600   C
103933  0        0     1-Apr-2011   NILESH BRANKS              850500   D
103934  0        0     1-Apr-2011   T.D.S ON CONTRACT A/C       45600   C
103935  0        0     1-Apr-2011   CHEQUE A/C                 185000   C
103936  0        0     1-Apr-2011   PROFESSIONAL CHARGES       619900   C
103937  0        0     1-Apr-2011   ADVERTISEMENT  (HOARDING)   77210   C
103938  0        0     1-Apr-2011   A111 COMMUNICATIONS         77210   D
103939  0        0     1-Apr-2011   SALARY A/C                  55500   D
103940  0        0     1-Apr-2011   T JOHN                      25000   C
103941  0        0     1-Apr-2011   PHILIPS                     30500   C
```

TxnAmt might be Credit (C) or Debit (D). Please note that for TxnID 103931 and 103932 Debit and credit are annulled. For those pairs I want to generate a unique VchNo (Voucher No), say 101 with sequence No 1 and 2 respectively.
For TxnID 103933 there is a debit amount (850500) which is equal to credit amounts of TxnID 103934, 103935 and 103936 (45600 + 185000 + 619900). I want to set VchNo as 102 for these a transactions with sequence no 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively as shown in the following result set:

```
TxnID   VchNo    SeqNo      Date    AccountName                TxnAmt   CrDr
103931  101      1     1-Apr-2011   ADVERTISEMENT                3600   D
103932  101      2     1-Apr-2011   MAYA OUTDOOR ADVERTISING     3600   C
103933  102      1     1-Apr-2011   NILESH BRANKS              850500   D
103934  102      2     1-Apr-2011   T.D.S ON CONTRACT A/C       45600   C
103935  102      3     1-Apr-2011   CHEQUE A/C                 185000   C
103936  102      4     1-Apr-2011   PROFESSIONAL CHARGES       619900   C
103937  103      1     1-Apr-2011   ADVERTISEMENT  (HOARDING)   77210   C
103938  103      2     1-Apr-2011   A111 COMMUNICATIONS         77210   D
103939  104      1     1-Apr-2011   SALARY A/C                  55500   D
103940  104      2     1-Apr-2011   T JOHN                      25000   C
103941  104      3     1-Apr-2011   PHILIPS                     30500   C
```

Assume the First Voucher Sequence No be 101, I want to update the VchNo and SeqNo as shown above.
Kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: I see '937 and '938 have the transactions in a different order. And '939, '940 and '941 don't add together at all. If '934 had been `45500` (i.e. 100 less), would '934, '935 and '936 still have been associated with '933? There are a lot of combinations of information not obviously present in your example.

Comment: Please correct your test data

Comment: Now the data is corrected. Pls help to achieve the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with a `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
;WITH YourData AS
(SELECT
    (list of columns),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VchNo ORDER BY TxnID DESC) AS 'SeqNo')
 FROM
    dbo.YourTable
 WHERE (condition)
)
SELECT * 
FROM YourData
```

Basically, the CTE partitions your data by `VchNo` - i.e. each `VchNo` defines a "partition" of data. The `ROW_NUMBER` function will sequentially number all rows, starting at each in each partition.

Just reread your question and it seems you don't have a `VchNo` value to begin with..... I don't completely understand is how you want to create your `VchNo` - these need to be based on some criteria, too - and I don't see anything in your original data that would "hold together" those values....

But you could definitely create two `ROW_NUMBER` function inside a single CTE, or you might need to do a first CTE for determining the `VchNo` and the a second one to determine the `SeqNo` based on that `VchNo` from the first CTE.

Comment: sorry for not responding, there was no internet from last 10 hours. I have edited the test data.

Comment: You should order by TxnID since date seems to be the same for all rows

Comment: @Nagesh: I still don't see how you keep a `C` and a `D` entry together.... how do you know which ones belong together?? Do they share a common column of some sort??

Comment: @marc_s Date is the only sort here.